# find the intersection of a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a vector, let say `as = [1 3 4]` and I have `30 by 30` cell array. I want to check if the elements of vector as intersect with the elements of each cell or not? the cells may be `2D` arrays of size `n-by-2` (where n= 1 2 3 4,etc).

If the row in a cell has an intersection with that vector, it should return `(1 or 0)` & if the row has no intersection with that vector, it should return `(0 or 1)`.

Example: 
If on of the cell arrays contains `[ 1 8 ;6 9]` , so the output is `[1; 0]`.

Comment: So, `all n` rows in each cell must have at least one intersection with  `as` or is it `any` row of each cell?

Comment: Can you use some actual minimal data for the cell array and show us the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `cellarr` to be input cell array, see if this approach works for you -

```
out = cellfun(@(x) any(any(bsxfun(@eq,x,permute(as,[1 3 2])),2),3),cellarr,'un', 0)
```

This would give you a cell array of all those matches for each cell. You can see their values with a call to `celldisp(out)`.

Sample run -

```
as =
     1     3     4
-----------------------------------
cellarr{1,1} =
     1     8
     6     9
cellarr{2,1} =
     7     4
     2     3
cellarr{1,2} =
     4     3
cellarr{2,2} =
     7     8
     2     3
     7     8
-----------------------------------
out{1,1} =
     1
     0
out{2,1} =
     1
     1
out{1,2} =
     1
out{2,2} =
     0
     1
     0
```

---

**Edit:** If you would like to find indices that do not have any zeros corresponding to their cell values in `out`, that is we intend to find cells where all rows have at least one element from `as`, you can use this modified code, assuming `ca` to be the input cell array (name changed here to keep the code compact) -

```
mch = cellfun(@(x) all(any(any(bsxfun(@eq,x,permute(as,[1 3 2])),2),3)),ca,'un',0)
                                                   %// Find matches for all cells
mch(cellfun('isempty',ca))={false} %// take care of empty cell condition
[row_ind,col_ind] = find(cell2mat(mch)) %// row and column indices of good matches
```

Comment: after that I want to return the indices of the cell arrays that does not have any zero in it ?

Comment: does your last command consider the empty cells ? , because in my case there will be some cell arrays that are empty & I don't want them to be considered in may calculations